# Accessing or omitting non-existing data

Tags: arrays, delphi, coordinates, gis

I'm performing some geographical computations in a grid with squares (i.e. regions). I'm using Delphi, but the logic could probably be applied to C++ too. Let me first explain what I want to do.

The following image is a portion of my grid, which is represented by a two-dimensional array `Square` that denotes the centre point in each square, and the "movement through the layers":

[image]

The green square has an X and Y coordinate of 2, so that is `Square[2,2]`. The actual coordinates are stored in `Square[2,2].Latitude` and `Square[2,2].Longitude` as wel as extra information in e.g. `Square[2,2].Info` that I use for computations.

Now comes the purpose: I need to do some computations on the surrounding areas. How many of the surrounding areas can be called "neighbours", depends on how many "layers" I have defined. In the image above, I used two of these "layers". That means that when starting from the green cell, I go around it once (blue arrows) and then again  in the second layer (red arrows).

Now comes the problem: if I would have started in `Square[1,1]` (green square) instead of `Square[2,2]` as in the image below, the second layer (in red) would try to access data on the left side and at the bottom that does not exist (i.e. in the "-1" column and row). See the image below. This problem occurs at all borders of course.

[image]

I probably can make exceptions with IF-statements for every scenario, but I was wondering if there are common programming "tricks" that can handle such situations where you try to access data does not exist.

For example, I imagine it would be very handy if I can follow the pattern of the arrows depicted in the first image to access all the neighbouring squares every single time, even if there are non-existing squares. So, looking at the first image, after `Square[3,0]` you'd go to something like `Square[3,-1]` etc. and then eventually come back into the "feasible" zone in `Square[0,3]`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as being too broad. StackOverflow is not for people to write algorithms for you, or recommend tutorials on algorithm design.  Please narrow the focus of your questions to specific issues.

Comment: Before trying to optimize your code, what is largest possible dataset you need to handle? Have you tried the conventional O(n) approach on the largest dataset by looping through every element? If visiting every element works, you probably can just do it that way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Sorry for that, I've edited the post to be more on-point and on the programming issue.

Comment: @user3437460: I've edited the post, my problem is that I need to identify the mentioned neighbouring locations and not per se try to omit processing "useless" data. Also, full enumeration that you propose would be possible, but this would limit the algorithm elsewhere, so indeed that is not preferred.

Comment: So, you're about to query GIS data? If so, then use [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) structure.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know R-trees, seems nice!

However, the pattern of the arrows that I've showed should be much easier in this case, as the tessellation (pattern) of locations is known and symmetrical. In the meantime I've almost found something that will work with the mentioned approach, just by using a plethora of if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

To visit neighborhood, you can use some kind of BFS (breadth-first search).

But for sparse structure (like the last picture shows) it is worth to use some data structure to organize cells in a good way. Perhaps [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is suitable - you add all existing cells in the tree and make range search around given cell to get other cells in its vicinity.

Also look at another spatial data structures (see list at the bottom of kd-tree page).

Comment: Shouldn't that be *breadth* first search? (You are not talking about something you buy in the bakery, do you?) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: Thanks, that would indeed be a possible method. However, if I would have a million locations it would be significantly inefficient to do such partitioning technique on all locations.

In my case, I know exactly what my neighbours and can access them with the arrows that I have illustrated. But the problem is how to program accessing locations that are outside the region and thus are non-existing. Or maybe this should be not as easy as I would think of course...